# PHP_Flag and PHP_Value Command Not Found Issue

Tags: php, apache-2.2

We currently have a dedicated server with one company that is running apache, php, mysql etc.  It currently has whm/cpanel installed.  We are migrating to a new server with cpanel/whm.  Everything migrated over fine but now one of my sites has some php_flag and php_value lines in the .htaccess file.  When I go to the site on this new server I am getting 500 errors that read Invalid command 'php_flag', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration.

I am not sure what I need to do to get these to work so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Putting `php_flag` etc in `.htaccess` is only possible when you are using `mod_php`.  With CGI/FCGI, Apache settings cannot be used to configure PHP since it is not running within Apache.

Using CGI, if you need a site with a custom php.ini, the exact details would depend on how exactly you're running the PHP (CGI, mod_fastcgi (with or without php-fpm), mod_fcgid).  For basic CGI you will need to create an alternate Action for php files in that site that executes a wrapper script containing something like `/usr/bin/php5-cgi -c /some/alternate/php.ini`